# Teacher-Student System: Training Student With k Target Sequences for Each Input Sequence

Tags: returnn

This question is related to [Teacher-Student System: Training Student with Top-k Hypotheses List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258957/teacher-student-system-training-student-with-top-k-hypotheses-list)

I want to configure a teacher-student system, where a teacher seq2seq model generates a top-*k* list of hypotheses, which are used to train a student seq2seq model.

I select the top-*k* hypotheses list from the teacher’s `ChoiceLayer` (or output layer) by:

```py
"teacher_hypotheses": {
    "class": "copy", "from": ["extra.search:teacherMT_output"],
    "register_as_extern_data": "teacher_hypotheses_stack"
}
```

The output `Data` of that layer has a batch axis length `batch_size`=*k*=4 times the length of the input `Data`’s batch axis length (cf. doc and code of: [`Data.copy_extend_with_beam`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/TFUtil.html?highlight=copy_extend_with_beam#TFUtil.Data.copy_extend_with_beam), [`SearchChoices.translate_to_common_search_beam`](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/TFNetworkLayer.html?highlight=SearchChoices#TFNetworkLayer.SearchChoices.translate_to_common_search_beam)).

`teacher_hypotheses_stack` is selected as the student’s training target. But this leads to the following error:

```sh
TensorFlow exception: assertion failed: [shape[0]:] [92] [!=] [dim:] [23]
     [[node studentMT_output/rec/subnet_base/check_seq_len_batch_size/check_input_dim/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at home/philipp/Documents/bachelor-thesis/returnn/returnn-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
```

Which is, I assume, due to the issue that the target data of the student, the hypotheses list, has a batch axis length *k*=4 times longer than the one of the student’s input data/encoder state data.

What do I have to do, to enable the student’s decoder to have *k* different target sequences for each input sequence?

**EDIT (12th June 2020)**: I took a look into the TensorFlow graph via TensorBoard, to inspect the node mentioned in the error. To me it looks like, the target’s batch axis length is validated against the batch axis length of the student’s overall input data (meaning the encoder input data). So this check seems to be independent of what I feed into the student’s decoder.

**EDIT (15th June 2020)**: Following Albert's advice, I opened an issue on GitHub, related to my problem: [Targeting Beam as Training Target Causes Dimension Error](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/issues/304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might actually be a bug. Via `register_as_extern_data`, I'm not exactly sure that the logic of `translate_to_common_search_beam` is correct. I think the code currently expects that a target never has a beam.

So, to answer your question: I think you are doing it already correct (so we can close this StackOverflow question).

You should open a GitHub issue about this (and then link it here). It would be good to come up with a simple test case:

- I.e. where there is some beam (you don't even need RecLayer for that, just a single ChoiceLayer would be enough I think),
- then `register_as_extern_data` on that,
- and then some other layer which uses this target in some way (e.g. just with `"loss": "ce"`).

Probably this will cause exactly your problem.

Comment: Okay, I opened an issue (see above).

Comment: @PhilippWynands So the question here is answered then, right?