# Loading Ground Truth and Hypotheses as Training Target

Tags: returnn

In an earlier question ([Teacher-Student System: Training Student With k Target Sequences for Each Input Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344553/teacher-student-system-training-student-with-k-target-sequences-for-each-input)), I wanted a teacher machine translation (MT) model to perform an online search during the training of a student speech translation (ST) model, to generate multiple targets per input sequence for the student.

Now, in the hope to speed things up, I want the teacher to perform the search offline. So, I let the teacher generate a hypothesis file containing the output of its `ChoiceLayer`.

My plan is to use these hypotheses and the ground truth as target for the student. So, for each input sequence from `source.train(.gz)` there is the ground truth target coming from `target.train(.gz)` and one or multiple teacher hypotheses coming from `teacher.train.hyp`.

In my online search config, I simply registered the teacher’s `Data` coming from its `ChoiceLayer` as `extern_data`. Since the `Data` contained a `SearchBeam`, RETURNN automatically regarded that the target `Data` consists of multiple sequences (this feature was added with issue [Targeting Beam as Training Target Causes Dimension Error #304](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/issues/304)). I want a similar automatism in my offline search solution.

My question is, does RETURNN already have components, with which my plan could be achieved, or do I have to write an extension for that? If I have to extend RETURNN for that, does anybody have recommendations on how to do that? (E.g. I thought about writing a special `TranslationDataset` subclass)

**EDIT (15.8.2020):**

First, let me answer Albert's question, on how my data currently looks like (which is subject to change, of course):

Currently, I don't make use of HDF files or `HDFDataset`. I use `MetaDataset` to combine an `ExternSprintDataset` and `TranslationDataset` to combine the ASR and the MT (ground truth) data for my ST student, but yet I'm not at the point where I load the teacher's hypotheses from any persistent data format.

However, I've dumped the teacher's hypotheses by simply selecting its `ChoiceLayer` (decoder `output`) as `search_output_layer`. Then, on search, RETURNN creates a text file (in my case I chose `teacher.train.hyp`), which contains the hypotheses per input sequence stored, basically as a string-serialized Python-dict, like this:

```py
{
'line-0': [
(-0.5233442, 'heute werde ich mit Ihnen über die letzten 30 Jahre der Archite@@ ktur@@ geschichte sprechen .'),
(-0.52996093, 'heute werde ich mit Ihnen über die letzten 30 Jahre der archite@@ kt@@ onischen Geschichte sprechen .'),
...
],
'line-1': [
(-0.68246835, 'das ist eine Menge , in 18 Minuten einzu@@ packen .'),
(-0.7289281, 'das ist eine Menge , um in 18 Minuten einzu@@ packen .'),
...
],
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RETURNN already has all the code/components to support that, but maybe it is currently not so nice. RETURNN of course will not know, when you load the hyps from `teacher.train.hyp`, that this is actually a beam (or supposed to be a beam). You could explicitly tell it, e.g. via `EvalLayer` (just identity, but you would specify `out_type`). But this depends how you have your data.

I actually wonder, how exactly is it stored in `teacher.train.hyp`? How did you store it? You used `HDFDumpLayer` on the search output? That included the beam, right? I just checked the `HDFDumpLayer` code, and I think, it will just ignore the beam. I.e. it effectively would store every sequence (identified by seq-tag) N times.

If that is the case, when you load that HDF file, it doesn't know about that. I wonder, when you combine it now with `MetaDataset`, doesn't it complain that the datasets don't have the same amount of sequences? But even if not, it probably ignores N-1 of the seqs, and just takes one of them.

So there are multiple questions:

- How you actually would want to store the seqs?

  - What file format? HDF? Or what comes out from search, i.e. the Python format you specified?
  - In what (shape/logical) format? How exactly? E.g. flatten all seqs behind each other? Then you also need to store the individual seq lens. Or how else? With padding? Whatever...
  - I assume you would want it to be compatible to the `HDFDataset`, right?
- How would you load the seqs?

  - Depending on file format:

    - If you have it compatible to `HDFDataset`, so you would use that, as part of a `MetaDataset`.
    - For the Python format of the search results, there is no dataset currently which can load/read that data. But we/you can of course implement such a dataset.
  - Now, depending on how the shape/logical format is, you would need to undo that (e.g. undo the flattening, e.g. via `UnflattenNdLayer`).
- How to tell RETURNN to use that as beam.

The last question is actually the most trivial question of all of them, and very much depends on the other questions. E.g. it could look like this:

```
"target_beam": {
  "class": "eval", "from": ..., "eval": "identity",
  "out_type": {"search_beam": SearchBeam(beam_size=12, name="targets")}}
```

(Maybe there are minor problems then. I'm not sure if anyone ever has tried to do it like this. But this would be issues you would report to the GitHub issue tracker.)

For this saving/storing in HDF, this is all possible, but needs lots of manual work in your config, so it's quite complicated. This has recently came up in a related discussion [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/issues/331) about making `HDFDataset` more flexible, to allow more custom formats, e.g. like for your case. So this is more a feature request, or ongoing discussion about implementation in RETURNN, and cannot really be answered here on StackOverflow.

For implementing a new dataset, this is actually not so difficult. I think it would be useful to have a dataset which can directly read the output of the search results. This should be quite easy, as it is already in Python format, so basically it is one `eval(open(...).read())`, and some logic around. (This would keep all in memory, which is maybe not optimal once you scale it up, but you could extend the implementation later.) The question is then also, in what format (shape) you would present the data to RETURNN. And then you end up to the other parts I explained above.

---

Better do not extend your question further. That makes it very difficult to follow the discussion. StackOverflow is intended to ask very specific, very direct questions, so that simple/direct answers can be given.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and for giving a useful subdivision of the problem! I appended an **EDIT** to my question, explaining the status quo on how my data is currently stored. But of course, this might change, while I'm searching for a solution of problem. Using `EvalLayer` to register my `Data` as beam looks like a good idea to me. So, there remain the question on the format of the persistent hypotheses data (e.g. HDF or Python-dict string) and the RETURNN internal representation (shapes etc.). So, you recommend looking into HDF files and `HDFDataset`?

Comment: I extended my answer. If there are follow-up questions, better post them as separate questions, and mark this one as solved. StackOverflow is intended for single atomic questions/answers.